# Why doesn't my article send after I wrote two mixins?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have written a view to send my form, but I had to level users, so I wrote two mixins, but now my author user can't send an article.

View:

```
from .mixins import FieldsMixin, FromValidMixin
class ArticleCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, FromValidMixin , FieldsMixin , CreateView):
    model = Article
    template_name = "registration/article-create-update.html"
```

Mixins:

```
from django.http import Http404

class FieldsMixin():
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            self.fields = ["author" ,"title" , "slug" , "category" , "description" , "thumbnail" , "publish" , "status"]
        
        elif request.user.is_author:
            self.fields = ["title" , "slug" , "category" , "description" , "thumbnail" , "publish" , "status"]

        else:
            raise Http404("You can't see this page")

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class FromValidMixin():
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            form.save()
        else:
            self.obj = form.save(commit=False)
            self.obj.author = self.request.user
            self.obj.status = 'd'
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

> but now my author user can't send an article.

Article that should also be written by `author` like `user`, you should also include `author` field in `self.fields` in `FieldsMixin` so:

```py
class FieldsMixin():
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser or request.user.is_author:
            self.fields = ["author", "title", "slug", "category", "description", "thumbnail", "publish", "status"]
        else:
            raise Http404("You can't see this page")

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```